# how to write action in which partial view action to be called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

My Parent Action where i want to render multiple Partial Views...

```
public ActionResult DashBoard()
{
    AttendanceController ac = new AttendanceController();
    ac.MyInformation();
    return View();
}
```

child Action which i want to made a partial view in DashBoard...

```
public ActionResult MyInformation()
{
    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var us = from u in db.Users
             join s in db.Designations
             on new { id = u.DesignationID } equals new { id = s.DesignationID }
             where u.Id == currentUserId

             select new ViewEmployees
             {

                 EmployeeCode = u.UserName,
                 EmployeeName = u.Name,
                 Father_Name = u.Father_Name,
                 DesignationName = s.DesignationName,
                 EmployeeType = u.EmployeeType,
                 Email = u.Email,
                 Mobile = u.Mobile

             };

    return PartialView("_MyInfo", us);
}
```

how can i add MyInformation(Partial View) into DashBoard

Comment: Why dont you simply use `@Html.Partial("_MyInfo")` in your view?

Comment: Would you mind accepting answers that helped you? That also directs future users to the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728618%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper. Your parent controller action should only render a view:

```
public ActionResult DashBoard()
{
    return View();
}
```

and inside this view:

```
@Html.Action("MyInformation", "Attendance")
```

You can read more about child actions and the difference between Html.Action and Html.Partial helpers in this post: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/

Comment: thnx..
now it working **perfectly**... @Darin Dimitrov

Comment: you should accept it as answer if thats what u needed @Usman407

Answer (score 0):

Change your Dashboard action to:

```
public ActionResult DashBoard()
{
    return View();
}
```

In your Master View (in your case the Dashboard view) use something like this:

```
<div id="myPartialView">
   @Html.Action("MyInformation", "ControllerName")
</div>
```

So a call will be made to the `MyInformation` action and the view returned by that action will be shown in the designated place.

Comment: don't you think its exact copy of the answer given by Darin 4 minz ago!!

Comment: @Neel Didn't knew Darin had already posted his answer. Took time for me to complete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RenderAction` inside the parent view. if you want as child view else use as defined by Darin

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MyInformation", "Attendance");}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Html.Action helper. Your parent controller action should only render a view:

```
public ActionResult DashBoard()
{
    return View();
}
```

and inside this view:

```
@Html.Action("MyInformation", "Attendance")
```